# Error after reaching the phone authentication limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been using Firebase from long time. I am curious about what is the error thrown by phone authentication when I cross monthly limit of 10K verifications?

Anyone have the idea?

Comment: This is a genuine question, if anyone has experienced this before then please answer.
First scenario could be, login page using phone auth crashes and users will uninstall the app thinking the app is not worthy.
Second scenario could be firebase would start charging the dev automatically after crossing the limit.
Let's assume that the app is making 3000 phone auth login requests daily across the globe.
Daily Ad revenue is less than few dollars but then Firebase starts charging 0.01$ per auth then dev is actually spending more than his earning after the phone auth limit has reached.

Comment: I understand this this not a development related question but on searching the internet, there is no information on what to expect if the once the limit reaches the monthly 10k mark.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive an email like this from the firebase team when your app reached the 10k limit. Basically in the app the phone authentication will not throw any error to the user or simply crash. (Good news). It will show login failed message to the user (Can live with). What to expect... User may end up trying other login options if available in the app like email or gmail or facebook or twitter to login. Or user maay quit the app assuming that the app is not working as expected. [image: Preview of the email received from Firebase team when we reached the limit]

Comment: When processing the phone authentication do you get any error? If yes what is the error?

Comment: No error, it will show a dialog saying can't login something went wrong with an OK button. User can try any other login method after that and use the app.